# Video appear in center of the webpage

Tags: css

The video on my site does not appear to be in the center even though I have applied the following,

```
<iframe style="margin: 0 auto; width: 400px;"src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x2fqouu" width="300" height="150" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

[Here](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/nayajeevan/) is the website.

Comment: In chrome it appears center aligned

Comment: Why do you have `width="300"` and a style of `width:400px`? Correct those discrepancies first. And the HTML spec says there __must__ be spaces between all attributes.

Comment: @MrLister: Isn't there space between the attributes?

Comment: Yes i had a look at it u have applied a text-align:center too, i will have a look at it and let u know

Comment: @ShenXu You have a missing space before the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML CODE:**
**Include one parent div in your iframe**

```
 <div class="demo">
                <iframe style="margin: 0 auto; width: 400px;"src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x2fqouu" width="300" height="150" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>    
    </div>
```

**CSS CODE:**
**CSS Code you can include in your stylesheet**

```
.demo{
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. Please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question

Answer (score 1):

An iframe is an inline element. That means `margin: 0 auto` doesn't work on it, and neither does `text-align: center`.

So possible solutions are any of

- Change its `display` value to `inline-block`, so the margins work
- Change its `display` value to `block`, so the text-align works
- Assign `text-align: center` to its parent element, in this case the `p` it sits in.